# How to rebuild libiberty.a with -fPIC flag

Tags: gcc, g++, archlinux

I've getting the following linking error while compiling mlpack:

```
[ 37%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libmlpack.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib/libiberty.a(cplus-dem.o): warning: relocation against `libiberty_demanglers' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib/libiberty.a(cp-demangle.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `cplus_demangle_builtin_types' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/build.make:1040: lib/libmlpack.so.3.4] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2106: src/mlpack/CMakeFiles/mlpack.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
```

It seems I need to recompile libiberty.a library with -fPIC flag. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/73928) on the issue. In my case I was able to fix things by downgrading a few packages (as described in the report):

- binutils 2.36.1-3
- gcc 11.1.0-3
- gcc-libs 11.1.0-3
- gcc fortran-11.1.0-3

Ultimately this should be resolved when [binutils](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/binutils/) gets updated.

Comment: I reinstalled my Arch thinking I screwed something up and was getting the same error. Finally I can build again -- thanks a ton!